# Проблема в повторной обработке объекта ifstream

Tags: c++, xcode7

В следующем коде второй цикл не проходит ни разу в Xcode, но в Visual Studio работает, как нужно:

```
int temp; char symbol;
std::ifstream ifs("a.txt");
while (ifs>>temp) cout<<temp<<' '; // перебор последовательности, как чисел.
cout<<endl;

ifs.seekg(0,ios::beg); // установка курсора в начало файла.
ifs.clear(); // очищение флага состояния.

while (ifs.get(symbol)) // перебор последовательности, как символов.
    if (symbol!=' ' && symbol!='\n') cout<<symbol<<' ';
ifs.close();
```

Второй цикл не проходит ни разу, когда в первом цикле достигнут конец файла. Все проведенные тесты указывают на проблему с флагами состояний. Но флаги состояния после метода 'clear()' сбрасываются, как и должно быть. Поэтому не могу разобраться с данной проблемой. Отпишитесь, пожалуйста, те кто сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять местами `seekg` и `clear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том, что метод `std::istream::seekg` в `c++11`:

> The function clears the eofbit flag, if set before the call.
>
> Функция очищает флаг `eof`, если он был установлен перед вызовом.

а в `c++98`:

> If the eofbit flag is set before the call, the function fails (sets failbit and returns).
>
> Если флаг `eof` был установлен перед вызовом функция выполняется с ошибкой (устанавливается `failbit`).

Т.е. если собирать с поддержкой `c++11`, то `seekg` нормально отработает если уже находились в конце файла. В противном случае вернет ошибку. Соответственно достаточно только поменять местами вызовы `seekg` и `clear` чтобы работало в обоих случаях.

Comment: Спасибо. Не зафиксировал внимание при чтение документации на этом пункте, моя ошибка)